# Given that $f$ is entire, $f(0) = 1$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = 1 +\frac{i}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}$, find $f(1 - 2i)$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be an entire function such that $f(0)=1$ and $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=1+\frac{i}{n}-\frac{1}{n^3}$ for each positive integer $n$. Find $f(1-2i)$.

**Ideas:** If $f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)=1+\frac{i}{n}-\frac{1}{n^3}$, then $f(n)=1+in-n^3$. This reassures me that $f(0)=1$ but does not help me otherwise...

This is a review question for an end-of-quarter exam, so I have no idea what information to pull from an entire quarter of material.

**Bottom line:** I know "entire" means that all derivatives exist at all points in the complex plane, but I do not see how that would help me here. I am also unsure of how a function defined at *integers* only will help me find the value of the function at a *complex number*.

I am not looking for a full solution just yet, but maybe a hint that would nudge me in the right direction.

Grazie mille!

Comment: Note, you don't even need to be told $f(0) = 1$. This follows from the continuity of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track. Note however that you can't conclude $f(n) = 1 + in - n^2$ (the values of $f(\frac{1}{n})$ you are told only hold for positive integers $n$; to obtain the expression for $f(n)$, you are effectively using the given formula for non-integer values of $n$).

Instead, you can see that the holomorphic function $g(z) = 1 + iz - z^2$ agrees with the holomorphic function $f$ on the set $\{\frac{1}{n} \mid n \in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: Yes ... that makes sense. I actually think we came up with that when discussing with classmates the first time around. Thanks!

Comment: Is this related to the Identity Theorem (which we have not discussed yet in class which would explain why I had no idea where to start)? If two functions agree on certain points, then they agree on all points? I know this is probably generalizing and lacking lots of details, but is that the direction I need to take?

Comment: Exactly. The [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) states that if two holomorphic functions agree on an open set, the two functions are equal. A stronger statement that only works in one dimension is that if two holomorphic functions agree on a set with an accumulation point, then the two functions are equal.

Comment: Excellent ... thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** :

Fact: let $f$ be an entire function and $Q_f$ be the set of its zero points. If the elements in $Q_f$ has a limit point in $Q_f$ then $f \equiv 0$ is a constant function.

Now the function $g(z) = f(z) - 1 - iz - z^3$ has zeros points including $\{\frac1n | n\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup \{0\}$ and $0$ is the limit point of $\{\frac1n | n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, thus $g$ is constantly $0$.

Comment: What should have made me think to compose $g(z)$ in the manner you did?